# Saving only the first word of a paragraph in a javascript variable

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store a paragraph in a javascript variable. I have multiple buttons inside a table, each one of the buttons has a different value, the value of each button is a small text paragraph. When i click a button a save the current buttons value in a javascript variable called 'input'.

When a button is clicked i also load an html form called "contactForm" and i display the buttons value inside that form.

The functionality works fine, the problem though is that when i save the value of the button in the ('input') js variable it saves only the first word of the paragraph, is there a way to fix this?

```html
<html>
     
      <div id="contactForm" >
            <p><h4><i>First Choose the clients and then the file which will be uploaded in order to proced</i></h4></2>
               <hr>
                <input type="text" id="someInput" name="someInput"></input>
               <hr>
        </div>
    <script>
    var input; //prepare var to save contact name/ PLACE outside document ready
    $(function() {
     // contact form animations
     $('button[id="contactbutton"]').click(function() {
       input = $(this).val(); //set var input to value of the pressed button
       document.getElementById("someInput").value = input;
        $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
      })
      $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#contactForm");
    
        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.fadeOut();
          
        }
      });
    
    });
    </script>

<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple and it works... I just didn't include the additional jQuery that you've written, as for getting the first word from a paragraph, it does do that though.

```html
<div id="contactForm" >
   <p>First Choose the clients and then the file which will be uploaded in order to proced</p>
  <hr>
  <input type="text" id="someInput" name="someInput">
  <hr>
</div>

<br>...
<br>
<h4>Demo</h4>
<button id ="contactbutton">Click Me</button>
<script>
  /**
   * @description the purpose of this function is to demonstrate how to 
   *              get the first word of a paragraph, sentence, etc.
   */
  !function() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('button[id="contactbutton"]');
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      // get the paragraph tag text
      var para = document.querySelector("#contactForm p").textContent;
      console.log(para);      
      
      // break the paragraph into an arraywor each word seperated by a space
      // index 0 = first element in the array 
      var word = para.split(" ")[0];
      console.log(word);
      
      // another example 
      var inp = document.querySelector("input#someInput");
      var inpVal = inp.value;
      console.log(inpVal);
      var word2 = inpVal.split(" ")[0];
      console.log(word2);
    });
  }();
</script>
```

Comment: Bro thank you but my only problem is that i want to save all the paragraph instead of only the first word

Comment: @user3397260 it already does that, I've included some console logs to demonstrate.... My solution does both, storing the entire string and getting only the first word from the string too.